# In Rx instead of only getting the last debounced object, can I get the complete sequence?

Tags: rxjs, rx-java, reactive

[image]

I want to know if one of the debounced objects was a green ball. Filtering for only green balls before or after the debounce leads to incorrect behavior.

Comment: Looks like you need a "group by" operator.

Comment: I can answer this, but you've tagged your question as `rxjs` and `rx-java`. Which is it? JavaScript or Java?

Comment: Rxjava specifically, I tagged both because I though the answer would be the same just different syntax.

Comment: What do you want to do with those green ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the buffer operator together with the debounce operator. Here a very basic example:

```
// This is our event stream. In this example we only track mouseup events on the document
const move$ = Observable.fromEvent(document, 'mouseup');

// We want to create a debounced version of the initial stream
const debounce$ = move$.debounceTime(1000);

// Now create the buffered stream from the initial move$ stream. 
// The debounce$ stream can be used to emit the values that are in the buffer
const buffered$ = move$.buffer(debounce$);

// Subscribe to your buffered stream
buffered$.subscribe(res => console.log('Buffered Result: ', res));
```

Comment: I've just seen that your question is for rx java. My example is for rxjs specifically, but it should work the same way with java.

Comment: Awesome thanks! This did the trick! I found also [the documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/buffer.html) has the RxJava version written up, it's the last example in the `RxJava 1.x buffer` drop down

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you want to achieve, you probably need to build an Observable which emits some sort of object which contains both the source value (i.e. blue, red, green in your case) as well as a flag that indicates whether or not there was a green in the debounced values.

If this is true, you can try to code along these lines

```
const s = new Subject<string>();

setTimeout(() => s.next('B'), 100);
setTimeout(() => s.next('G'), 1100);
setTimeout(() => s.next('B'), 1200);
setTimeout(() => s.next('G'), 1300);
setTimeout(() => s.next('R'), 1400);
setTimeout(() => s.next('B'), 2400);

let hasGreen = false;

s
.do(data => hasGreen =  hasGreen || data === 'G')
.debounceTime(500)
.map(data => ({data, hasGreen})) // this map has to come before the following do
.do(() => hasGreen =  false)
.subscribe(data => console.log(data))
```

Be careful about the sequence. In particular you have to put the `map` operator which creates the object you want to emit before the `do` that resets your variable.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done with a non-trivial set of operators and side-effecting a flow by introducing extra channels:

```java
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

import org.junit.Test;

import io.reactivex.*;
import io.reactivex.functions.Consumer;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.*;
import io.reactivex.subjects.PublishSubject;

public class DebounceTimeDrop {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        PublishSubject<Integer> source = PublishSubject.create();

        TestScheduler scheduler = new TestScheduler();

        source.compose(debounceTime(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, scheduler, v -> {
            System.out.println(
                    "Dropped: " + v + " @ T=" + scheduler.now(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
        }))
        .subscribe(v -> System.out.println(
                "Passed: " + v + " @ T=" + scheduler.now(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)),
                Throwable::printStackTrace, 
                () -> System.out.println(
                        "Done "  + " @ T=" + scheduler.now(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)));

        source.onNext(1);
        scheduler.advanceTimeBy(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        scheduler.advanceTimeBy(20, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        source.onNext(2);
        scheduler.advanceTimeBy(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        source.onNext(3);
        scheduler.advanceTimeBy(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        source.onNext(4);
        scheduler.advanceTimeBy(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        source.onNext(5);
        scheduler.advanceTimeBy(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        scheduler.advanceTimeBy(20, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        source.onNext(6);
        scheduler.advanceTimeBy(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        scheduler.advanceTimeBy(20, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        source.onComplete();
    }

    public static <T> ObservableTransformer<T, T> debounceTime(
            long time, TimeUnit unit, Scheduler scheduler, 
            Consumer<? super T> dropped) {
        return o -> Observable.<T>defer(() -> {
            AtomicLong index = new AtomicLong();
            Queue<Timed<T>> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

            return o.map(v -> {
                Timed<T> t = new Timed<>(v, 
                    index.getAndIncrement(), TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
                queue.offer(t);
                return t;
            })
            .debounce(time, unit, scheduler)
            .map(v -> {
                while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
                    Timed<T> t = queue.peek();
                    if (t.time() < v.time()) {
                        queue.poll();
                        dropped.accept(t.value());
                    } else
                    if (t == v) {
                        queue.poll();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                return v.value();
            })
            .doOnComplete(() -> {
                while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
                    dropped.accept(queue.poll().value());
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

prints

```
Passed: 1 @ T=10
Dropped: 2 @ T=43
Dropped: 3 @ T=43
Dropped: 4 @ T=43
Passed: 5 @ T=43
Passed: 6 @ T=73
Done  @ T=93
```